# Build a JSON Tree with Recursion

Tags: java, json, recursion, jackson, mapping

I want to recursively create a JSON tree from multiple strings. A string might like this:

```
.this.is:0.a.test
```

The character string is interpreted as follows:

- `.` is an object
- `:` is an array
- `:0.` is the first object in the
  array

The corresponding JSON looks like this

```
{
   "this":{
      "is":[
         {
            "a":{
               "test":"testvalue"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
public static JsonNode recursiveLimb(ArrayList<String> limb, Map<String, String> mappingBodyMap, BidiMap<String, String> bidiMap, JsonNode currentTree, String path) {

        if (!limb.isEmpty() && limb.get(0).equals(".")) {
            //object node

            String firstElem = limb.remove(0);
            String secondElem = limb.remove(0);
            //call recursion to build rest of tree
            JsonNode resultJN = recursiveLimb(limb, mappingBodyMap, bidiMap, currentTree, path + firstElem + secondElem);

            return mapper.createObjectNode().set(secondElem, resultJN);

        } else if (!limb.isEmpty() && limb.get(0).equals(":")) {
            //array node

            String firstElem = limb.remove(0);
            String secondElem = limb.remove(0);
            //call recursion to build rest of tree
            JsonNode resultJN = recursiveLimb(limb, mappingBodyMap, bidiMap, currentTree, path + firstElem + secondElem);

            return mapper.createArrayNode().add(resultJN);

        } else {
            //value node 

            String value = bidiMap.getKey(path);
            return new TextNode(mappingBodyMap.get(value));
        }
    }
```

This code returns all individual links of the tree. The problem is, I'm having a hard time putting them together. Hopefully someone can help me. Does someone have an idea what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of using this it would be easier to create a string and convert it to JSON at the end. Example: *.life.is:0.so.good* -> We start reading from the end;

1. We find . we create so:{good=goodValue}
2. We find :0. is:[{so:{good=goodValue}}]
3. We find . life:{is:[{so:{good=goodValue}}]}
4. We find the last . we added {life:{is:[{so:{good=goodValue}}]}}

I believe your solution is good, I just wanted to simplify the problem so it is still up to you.

Comment: Yes sounds good but how do you merge multiple of these jsons in the end?

Comment: GSON-JsonParser would be a good idea. Here is the link for examples, http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson-jsonparser.html